# how to compare 2 table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named `joy_gallery` and `joy_category`.

- **`joy_gallery`**

  ```
  ╔════╦════════╦════════╗
  ║ id ║ cat_id ║ images ║
  ╠════╬════════╬════════╣
  ║ 1  ║ 1      ║ a.png  ║
  ║ 2  ║ 1      ║ a1.png ║
  ║ 3  ║ 2      ║ b1.png ║
  ║ 4  ║ 1      ║ c.jpg  ║
  ║ 5  ║ 2      ║ d.jng  ║
  ║ 6  ║ 2      ║ a1.png ║
  ╚════╩════════╩════════╝
  ```
- **`joy_category`**

  ```
  ╔═════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
  ║ Cid ║ category ║ Description ║
  ╠═════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
  ║ 1   ║ onam     ║ xcfghhyjkk  ║
  ║ 2   ║ xmas     ║ hjytigkuyy  ║
  ╚═════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
  ```

I will to compare the two tables, display the two categories and the last image from each categories like this, `1 onam  c.jpg` and `1 xmas  a1.jpg`. I am using this mysql code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM joy_gallery INNER JOIN joy_category ON joy_gallery.cat_id = joy_category.Cid
ORDER BY joy_category.Cid DESC;
```

But it don't work. Display first category and 2 images from same category. How can I solve this? How to display the last image from a category?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT j1.* FROM joy_gallery j1
  JOIN (SELECT cid, MAX(cid) id FROM joy_category GROUP BY cid) j2
    ON j1.cat_id = j2.cid ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be more efficient ways of doing this, but one solution is :

```
SELECT cat_id, images 
FROM 
    (SELECT MAX(galI.gaid) gaid 
    FROM joy_gallery galI INNER JOIN joy_category cat 
    ON galI.cat_id = cat.Cid GROUP BY cat_id) galIn 
INNER JOIN joy_gallery gal USING(gaid);
```

Comment: Iam using this code ..but i got an error :Unknown column 'galIn.gaid' in 'field list'..

Comment: What database are you using? Maybe create the alias with "as galIn"

Comment: im using mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Your query could be like this: (`tested`)

```
SELECT joy_category.Cid, joy_category.category, joy_gallery.images FROM joy_gallery
JOIN joy_category
ON joy_gallery.cat_id = joy_category.Cid AND 
joy_gallery.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(joy_gallery.id)
    FROM joy_gallery
    GROUP BY joy_gallery.cat_id
)
```

Output:

```
 Cid    category    images  
----------------------------
  1       onam       c.jpg
  2       xmas      a1.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT a.Cid, a.category, c.images
FROM joy_category a
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT max(gaid) as id, cat_id
     FROM joy_gallery
     GROUP BY cat_id
) b ON b.cat_id = a.Cid
LEFT JOIN joy_gallery c ON c.gaid = b.id
```

Note : This's not tested, but I think it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT
    r.Cid,
    r.category,
    b.images 
FROM
    joy_category b
JOIN joy_gallery r ON r.Cid  = b.cat_id 
AND r.id = (
    SELECT
        MAX (x.id)
    FROM
        joy_gallery x
    WHERE
        x.cat_id  = b.Cid 
);
```